# Create a script to open firefox with some google search term from terminal

Tags: command-line, firefox, scripts

Is there any way to create a script or a program that will open firefox, go onto google and search for the arguments passed to it ?

So something like

```
google How do I shoot web
```

should open Firefox with http://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+shoot+web

I found this script

```
google() {
    search=""
    echo "Googling: $@"
    for term in $@; do
        search="$search%20$term"
    done
    xdg-open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$search"
}
```

but I need to paste it into the terminal each time I want to use it ...

So basically, what do I have to do to make the above script work without having to paste it into the terminal every time ?

Comment: Additionally, just typing your query directly in Firefox's URL bar will do a google search directly. In your case, just type 'How do I shoot web' and press enter.

Comment: Related to http://superuser.com/questions/47192/google-search-from-linux-terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just paste the below function inside `~/.bashrc` file and then source(`source ~/.bashrc`) it.

```
google() {
    search=""
    echo "Googling: $@"
    for term in $@; do
        search="$search%20$term"
    done
    xdg-open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$search"
}
```

After that you can open google search page directly by  `google search-string` command without pasting the above function everytime on terminal.